# Silent exception when binding PivotItem header

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, binding, windows-phone-7.1, pivotitem

I've noticed a strange exception in my Windows Phone 7.1 application that really made me crazy.

These are the facts...

I start defining a simple `Pivot` item with two simple `PivotItem` inside:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <controls:Pivot>
        <controls:PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem1"
                            Header="Test1" />
        <controls:PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem2"
                            Header="{Binding Path=Text2, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </controls:Pivot>
    <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And this is my code-behind...

EDIT: As Gambit suggested me, I will show you more code.

In the real situation, **I DO HAVE** A MVVM, but in this case I simplified the situation to let you reproduce the problem in an easy way...

For this test the next is my View:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text2 = "<Missing>";

    public string Text2
    {
        get
        {
            return _text2;
        }
        private set
        {
            _text2 = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text2");
        }
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text2 = "Second page";
    }
}
```

So, it's not just the parameter initialization of a `NULL` value: you will see the exception.

Obviously, you are asking me for the `controls` namespace declaration. This is:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
```

This refers to the assembly `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll`, version **2.0.50727**.

My problem is related to the binding (as I discovered investigating the problem):

```
Header="{Binding Path=Text2, Mode=OneWay}"
```

If you do not use bindings linked to the `Header` property of the `PivotItem`, everything works well, otherwise...the app will throw an exception, completely silent, and it won't show up in any case (you can see the exception only in the Output Window):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll
```

If you assign the `Header` property manually, no exceptions will be thrown.

I want to completely remove this exceptions, because I have a lot of bindings to the Header property, I don't want to break my MVVM...and it's also very annoying!

I really hate to see unmanaged exceptions...

Does anyone know about this problem?

Any solution/workaround?

Any help will be very appreciated...thank you!

Comment: I am not getting any exception when I use your code. Is there anything which might have caused this?

Comment: @MilanAggarwal Neither in the Output Window?

Comment: Mmmm...that's strange. I will continue my tests...thank you for the help!

Comment: no problem. Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, I would suspect that the issue is the DataContext is not being set.  In your example, the DataContext is set in the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event. However, it doesn't appear that you are registering for this event anywhere.  In the constructor of MainPage, add a line like:

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded);
```

Comment: The registration of the event is defined in XAML correctly...this sample works, and also the bindings. How can I bind the DataContext before the Loaded event? Except for the View constructor...but I prefer not to set the DataContext there! thanks again!

Comment: It is probably easier to just set the DataContext in XAML.  See here for example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746695.aspx

Comment: Ok...but my I NEED to bind it dinamically! And why does this happen only with PivotItem?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are trying to achieve. As long as the binding of the Header of the PivotItem is referencing a valid value (i.e. DataContext is set so it can find it and the property is valid), binding in PivotItem works same as anything else. The DataContext should basically be set to your ViewModel object. Are you trying to attach different ViewModels to the same View?